# ActiveRecord polymorphic association with unique constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, models

I have a site that allows users to log in via multiple services (LinkedIn, Email, Twitter, etc..).

I have the below structure set up to model a `User` and their multiple identities. Basically a user can have multiple identieis, but only one of a given type (e.g. can't have 2 Twitter identiteis).

I decided to set it up as a polymorphic relationship, as drawn below. Basically there's a middle table `identities` that maps a `User` entry to multiple `*_identity` tables.

[image: schema]

The associations are as follows (shown only for `LinkedInIdentity`, but can be extrapolated)

```
# /app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :identities
  has_one :linkedin_identity, through: :identity, source: :identity, source_type: "LinkedinIdentity"

  ...
end


# /app/models/identity
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :identity, polymorphic: true

  ...
end


# /app/models/linkedin_identity.rb
class LinkedinIdentity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :identity, as: :identity
  has_one :user, through: :identity

  ...
end
```

The problem I'm running into is with the `User` model. Since it can have multiple identities, I use `has_many :identities`. However, for a given identity type (e.g. LinkedIn), I used `has_one :linkedin_identity ...`.

The problem is that the `has_one` statement is `through: :identity`, and there's no singular association called `:identity`. There's only a plural `:identities`

```
> User.first.linkedin_identity
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :identity in model User
```

Any way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like so - i've changed the relationship name between Identity and the others to `external_identity`, since saying `identity.identity` is just confusing, especially when you don't get an Identity record back.  I'd also put a uniqueness validation on Identity, which will prevent the creation of a second identity of the same type for any user.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :identities
  has_one :linkedin_identity, through: :identity, source: :identity, source_type: "LinkedinIdentity"
end


# /app/models/identity
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  #fields: user_id, external_identity_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :external_identity, polymorphic: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :external_identity_type, :scope => :user_id
  ...
end


# /app/models/linkedin_identity.rb
class LinkedinIdentity < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Force the table name to be singular
  self.table_name = "linkedin_identity"

  has_one :identity
  has_one :user, through: :identity

  ...
end
```

**EDIT** - rather than make the association for linkedin_identity, you could always just have a getter and setter method.

```
#User
def linkedin_identity
  (identity = self.identities.where(external_identity_type: "LinkedinIdentity").includes(:external_identity)) && identity.external_identity
end    

def linkedin_identity_id
  (li = self.linkedin_identity) && li.id
end    

def linkedin_identity=(linkedin_identity)
  self.identities.build(external_identity: linkedin_identity)
end

def linkedin_identity_id=(li_id)
  self.identities.build(external_identity_id: li_id)
end
```

EDIT2 - refactored the above to be more form-friendly:  you can use the linkedin_identity_id= method as a "virtual attribute", eg if you have a form field like `"user[linkedin_identity_id]"`, with the id of a LinkedinIdentity, you can then do `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` in the controller in the usual way.

Comment: Why would you explicitly set a table name of `linkedin_identity`? I ask because leaving it as `linkedin_identities` makes sense as it is to me.

Comment: Good point on the confusing nature of naming it `identity.identity`. I like the uniqueness constraint on the `identities` table that prevents more than one record being created for a given `user_id` and `_type` combination. However, the original problem still persists - I can't call `user.linkedin_identity` because that association is through `:identity` (singular), which doesn't exist. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you change the `through` option to be `through :identities`?>

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Unfortunately not, rails doesn't like the `through:` param being a plural collection  ----  `ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection: Cannot have a has_one :through association 'User#linkedin_identity' where the :through association 'User#identities' is a collection. Specify a has_one or belongs_to association in the :through option instead.`

Comment: Maybe the assocation isn't going to work: use a method instead.  see my edit.

Comment: Thanks! I fell back on using that. Both yours and munichkine's answer below are great, as they are two options for workarounds. Didn't know if Rails Associations had something more succinct to support this, but looks like not. Marking yours accepted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just added another EDIT with a bit of refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea that has worked wonderfully over here for such as case. (My case is a tad diffferent since all identites are in the same table, subclasses of the same base type).

```
class EmailIdentity < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.unique_for_user
    false
  end

  def self.to_relation
    'emails'
  end
end

class LinkedinIdentity < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.unique_for_user
     true
  end

  def self.to_relation
    'linkedin'
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :identities do
      [LinkedinIdentity EmailIdentity].each do |klass|
        define_method klass.to_relation do
          res = proxy_association.select{ |identity| identity.is_a? klass }
          res = res.first if klass.unique_for_user
          res
        end
      end
   end
end
```

You can then

```
@user.identities.emails
@user.identities.linkedin
```

Comment: Interesting! I was hoping there was a more native Rails way to solve this, but looks from your solution that there is not :( But I do like the approach, so I might use that if no native ways pop up. Thanks!

Comment: It's actually native since ActiveRecord added relations extensions. Check the documentation for it. You can add a lot more interface methods to your relations for best efficiency!